# HTML and body doesn't have 100% width

Tags: html, css

My [portfolio site](https://www.jenlky.com/) has a white gap on the right at smaller width say 425px and below (especially on mobile devices). The reason because HTML and body does not inherit full width. Why is this so? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White gap is because you have some elements with width that is not relative on mobile resolution. For example, these three `p` tags has fixed width:
[image]

Just change its width to 100% on resolution below 768px.

**NOTE** I didn't check rest of your code, but I think this should solve your problem

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion. OP should either set the width inside media queries are use % values.

Comment: ah what a silly mistake... Is there any place I can read up more on this topic?

Comment: @helplah this is general knowledge about responsive web design. Take a look at this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/?hl=en)